# How to retrieve finish date from any task ID in a custom column? (custom field?)

Tags: formula, ms-project

I am tracking documentation, and using MS Project to get an overview of the actual duration of the tasks e.g.:

```
### ID | task | Duration  | Start | Finish  ###
1 | Document version 1 issue | 0 days | date1 | date1

2 | Comments version 1       | 0 days | date2 | date2

3 | Document version 2 issue | 0 days | date3 | date3

4 | Review approval ver 2    | 0 days | date4 | date4
```

All the tasks depends of externals so that's why duration is set to 0 and Start-finish are the same date. Depending on the document it might take longer to review and approve.

What I would like to do is to add another column, that is easy to add, to calculate what is the actual duration between the tasks. For example:

```
### ID | task | Duration  | Start | Finish | DAYS ###
1 | Document version 1 issue | 0 days | date1 | date1 | 

2 | Comments version 1       | 0 days | date2 | date2 | days between ID2 and ID1

3 | Document version 2 issue | 0 days | date3 | date3 | days between ID3 and ID2

4 | Review approval ver 2    | 0 days | date4 | date4 | days between ID4 and ID3
```

I have tried to use Customs Fields but cannot figure out how to retrieve the date of a chosen Task ID (in another row) within another Task ID row.

Let's say I would make something like

DateDiff("d",Finish([ID]),Finish([ID]-1)

Then I would expect to get the days differences so I can learn from experience how long does it actually take to review certain information.

Any suggestion to carry out this task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK Based on this sentence at the end...

> Then I would expect to get the days differences so I can learn from experience how long does it actually take to review certain information.

...I would suggest NOT doing any special coding. Rather, I would suggest you change the structure of your schedule. I would put in 'Review' Tasks between these milestones that represent the work of doing the reviews. Initially their durations would be estimates based on the size and nature of the thing being reviewed but that could be updated as the review process goes on.

If you MUST structure it this way then here is the code:

```
Sub CalcCustomDuration()
Dim P As Project
Dim T As Task
Set P = Application.ActiveProject
For Each T In P.Tasks
    If Not (T Is Nothing) Then
        If T.Number1 > 0 Then
            T.Number2 = Application.DateDifference(P.Tasks(T.ID - 1).Finish, T.Start) / 60 / 8
        End If
    End If
Next T
End Sub
```